# How to fit and crop group of images to conatiner width and reach equal height for them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any easy wy to reach the effect the same as on this page?

[eqal height and fit some images to container width](https://osmanfiderarslan.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches. I personally like the technique of setting the images as backgrounds of container elements and then using **[`background-size:cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)** or `:contain` along with sizing the containers and perhaps using **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)** to organize the containers into rows and columns.

But, ultimately, **you're going to have to have images that compliment your layout goal by having the right aspect ratios and orientations**.